# Highcharts: Individually Set Axis Category Style

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Given a chart like the example for [setting category label styles](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/xaxis/labels-style/), how can I set styles for each label individually? E.g., make "Jan" red, "Feb" green, and so on.

Here's the pertinent part of the JSFiddle, which sets all categories to red:

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
            labels: {
                style: {
                    color: 'red'
                }
            }
        },

        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
        }]
    });
});
```

I could use a formatter method to wrap each label in HTML and then conditionally set its style based on `this.value`, but surely there's a more direct approach?

Comment: AFAIK There is not a more direct way, actually. There are a variety of specific approaches, all of which require checking the value in the formatter and acting accordingly (I would set a CSS class, and style it externally, personally).

Comment: I would follow suggestion by @jlbriggs - use CSS classes. Of course, we can set styles inline, directly in the `categories` array. However, it will set color in the tooltip too: http://jsfiddle.net/zLwx6ymw/

Comment: I was afraid of that. I'll just go with @jlbriggs approach. Thanks for the pointers!